# "Он житейски неопытен": the usage of "житейски" (versus "по-житейски")

Tags: словоупотребление

> он **житейски** неопытен

It seems the word "житейски" is separately listed far below in the conjugation [table](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) of the adjective "житейский", and I'm not so familiar with its usage.

Is "житейски" an adverb derived from the adjective "житейский": "he's **worldly** inexperienced" or "inexperienced **in life**"? I assume it follows the same conjugational pattern seen in "я говорю **по-русски**".

If so, I wonder if it is odd to say:

> он **по-житейски** неопытен
>
> or: он неопытен **по-житейски**

When should I use "житейски" versus "по-житейски"?

Comment: As far as I can see, this word becomes outdated. Thus, a fair answer would be "you shouldn't use this word".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **житейски** is an adverb.

But it's used to describe passive participles answering the question *in what way?* similar to how the adverb functions in the English phrase `he's artistically gifted` or in a Russian phrase `он художественно одарён`, and adjectives `politically correct` - `политически корректный`.

**По-житейски** is a standard adverb which describes verbs and (adverbial) participles.

Comment: For instance, I say something like the following in conversation: "Хотя она ведет себя не **по-женски**, когда на нее никто не смотрит". So does "женски" without "по" sound odd here?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens yes, it absolutely does, not least because there's no such adverb as женски, and in fact по-женски is also used with passive participles and adjectives similarly to житейски... at first glance there seems to be no clear rule as to the correspondence of adverbs with specific parts of speech: verbs, participles and adjectives

Answer (score 2):

Qualitative adverbs originating from possessive adjectives in sg. inst. come in two varieties in Russian:

1. The adjective they modify describes some quality **pertinent** to the noun from which the adverb is formed:

   > - Он идеологически подкован // He's well versed in ideological matters (lit. "he's ideologically heeled")
   > - Баллистически стойкая ткань // Ballistic-proof fabric (lit. "ballistically proof")
2. The adjective they modify describes some quality **similar** to the noun from which the adverb is formed. They usually come with the preposition *по-*:

   > - Он по-гусарски расточителен // He's as prodigal with money as a hussar (lit. "hussarly prodigal")
   > - Макароны по-флотски // Pasta a la navy, a dish similar to ragu bolognese (lit. "navally (cooked) pasta, pasta as they do in the navy")

If you look closely, there is a difference between those adjectives.

The ones from the first list are *about* the thing the adverb describes: ideology *is* something which is good, ballistic *is* something the fabric is proof against etc.

The ones from the second list are *like* the thing the adverb describes: he's prodigal *like* a hussar, the pasta is *like* they do in the navy etc.

However, this is quite a fine line, and some of the adjectives are bleeding from one category to another. There is a number of adjectives like *героически, чертовски, ангельски, дьявольски, творчески* etc. which should have had the *по-* before them but they don't:

> - Он дьявольски умён // He's smart as a devil
> - Защитники Москвы героически пали на поле боя // The defenders of Moscow had fallen on the battlefield like heroes

In both those cases, *по-* would have had more sense.

*Житейски* in your example belongs to the first category: his everyday skills are *what* he is inexperienced at, not *like* something he's inexperienced at. Taken literally, *он по-житейски неопытен* would mean something like "he's inexperienced the way those who live their daily lives are", which makes little sense.

However, as I said, this is quite a fine line, and *по-житейски* and *житейски* are sometimes mixed:

> - Смагин был обеспечен, перспективен и совершенно по-житейски неопытен.
> - Губернатор Краснодарского края Александр Ткачёв заявил, что станица Кущёвская – это "по-житейски благополучное место"

Comment: i'd guess that the use of героически stems from the fact that it's not perceived as immediately related to герой, probably being overshadowed by геройски, which IS prefixed with по- in the context of death on the battlefield

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка corpus search for _геройски + V_ yields 204 documents, _по-геройски + V_ yields only two (and even those two are artifacts, not the real matches)

Comment: OK, but it doesn't sound off to me and Google gives more than enough matches to go about, even if that's not a literary norm, it's seems to be quite at home in the language

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка sure, as I said, the usage of *по-* does sway to and from

Comment: not sure how far fetched this is but героически might be even unable to receive по- prefix because of not being derived from герой within Russian language proper instead being adapted directly from foreign languages similarly to other adjectives/adverbs formed with the suffix -ически/й - электрический, прозаический, статический etc., whereas геройски is a native Russian derivation, don't think i can recall any -ически adverb having also the по- prefix

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка *по-таврически, по-наёмнически, по-жульнически* etc., basically, any adverb formed from a noun in *-ик* (or *-icus/-ikos* in original Latin or Greek).

Comment: I just want to add a word of comment regarding using по- vs skipping it. Russian is unique in a sence that using morphological elements can create incredibly subtle shades of meaning like hardly ever other languages do.
По-героически vs. Героически is one of those instances. If you speak of highly heroic deeds, по-героически feels clearly misplaced, it is more proper to say героически. The difference between the usage of the two words comes from the level of education and emotional intelligence.
I recall the best example i remember since i was six, believe it or not.
“Can i smoke when i say a

Answer (score 1):

That means "**inexperienced in life**". And I wouldn't add **по-** here.